# My question was dupe-hammered, but the supposed original did not answer the question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, dupehammer

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827873/adding-elements-to-front-and-back-of-char-array-of-unknown-size) (that supposedly didn't have an explicit answer on SO but I knew it was relatively simple) that was evaluated as a duplicate by a user seemingly just from the outlook of what I was asking. I can see how it sounded like a question without prior research, but it seemed like this user just grabbed the first look-a-like question, linked it and said "This is where your answer is, you didn't look properly" and closed my question.

It did NOT answer my question and in fact someone more helpful had answered it very concisely in a comment to which I appended to my question accordingly due to the lack of a formal answer. This answer was nowhere present on the post that I had supposedly duplicated and other users are more likely to skip past my question holding the answer that may have solved their problem because of this unhelpful dupehammer. Even the user's comments seemed condescending and were quite unhelpful giving off an aura that he thought I did not know what I was talking about.

I replied to the user that marked the question as duplicate and explained why, in my eyes, it may not be appropriate and expected a reply from him detailing otherwise but it never came. He neither clarified why he still believed it to be left marked as a dupe nor remove it. In it's current state, users looking for the same answer I was will end up not finding it without actually reading through my post and finding the answer which defeats the purpose of marking it as duplicate imo.

How do you appeal against a duplicate marker than you believe to be erroneous, i.e. bring in more users to confirm whether or not it is indeed an appropriate dupehammer use.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but when you take a very aggressive and/or accusatory tone in meta posts, it is not going to help you.  If you really want constructive feedback, then I suggest making this post much more nuetral

Comment: I didn't realise it was aggressive. Which parts of it made it sound like that?
EDIT: I realise I use 'unhelpful' quite a bit here, it's just that I expected those that can close questions so easily to be a bit more helpful or thorough

Comment: The entire post reads like a rant against the user who used his dupehammer (the word "hastily" in the title is a bad start).

Comment: @Shiri I don't think your Q is aggressive, but maybe just the "a user with a gold badge hastily (and unhelpfully) decided to dupehammer [...]" part might be a little better phrased.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've since toned down the title, I see how it could seem slightly aggressive

Comment: The title is still too confrontational if you ask me. A wise person once told me: make it about a thing, not about a person. "The question was dupe hammered", not "this person dupe hammered it"

Comment: Oh please, get array size from pointer?  There must be thousands of dups, in one form or another.

Comment: OK, most are 'failed to get array size from pointer' but still...

Comment: ..and the ever-popular 'what is the difference between an array and a pointer?'

Answer (score 5):

It is in fact a duplicate.  The link points to an answer that explains why you are doing it wrong.  The fact that you did not understand that answer and just forged ahead anyway by doing it wrong with `strlen()` is not a good reason to re-open the question.

Because if we would then we would just have to repeat the exact same answer.  With very significant odds that such an answer is completely useless to you because you won't understand it for the exact same reason.  Avoiding useless Q+A is a very strong goal at SO.

You can ask a new question, I recommend "Why is using strlen() the wrong way to measure the array size" as the title.  Make sure to point out that you are aware that there's an existing answer, only way you'll get a personalized answer that is more likely to help you understand the issue.

Comment: Agreed -- though I think the awkward aspect about X/Y questions is that if the person asking about the question knew about `strlen`, he wouldn't have asked it in the first place. I think as long as the site puts very basic questions on a flat footing with everything else, it ends up irritating both beginner and advanced alike. But I don't know what to do about it. I personally want to see pro/enthusiast-quality answers -- never cared that much about dupes, just interesting things to read that might teach me something new. Basic troubleshooting questions, dupes or not, don't teach me anything.

Comment: ... meanwhile advanced questions, even if they're dupes, might yield answers that teach me something new that didn't in the former Q. I see it all from the educational standpoint -- looking for things I can't find in a "C For Beginners" book, even if just opinions from veterans.

Answer (score 3):

I have conflicting thoughts on duplicate redirections here. I care deeply about the site's posterity and seeing really interesting and challenging (sometimes even broad or opinionated) questions, especially since I hang out in tags like [c] and [c++] which can be like a wasteland of very basic and boring questions (at least from a professional/enthusiast viewpoint) with little activity, and people racing to give a troubleshooting answer where, even if a Q has a lot of activity, it's just like 10 people providing a near-identical answer.

Nevertheless, I see my share of people kind of getting the cold shoulder treatment with a redirection which glosses over those subtleties. Another thing I see reasonably often (though through my biased and selective view) is a redirection based solely on the question [this question is similar to that one] even though the answers already provided to the one that got marked as a dupe tackled those subtle differences in a way that gave the new question a whole lot of meaning and flavor. Subtle differences in a question can have an enormous impact on the answers, and one thing I hate seeing is a question marked as a duplicate too late (after the Q already got up-voted a lot and got some really interesting answers).

At that point the Q&A has already become quite unique and distinct in character: too distinct to consider it a simple dupe, because the answers between the two Q&As are too different even if the questions are reasonably similar: the answers have branched out and diverged considerably based on the subtle differences at that point.

In your case, this is a grey zone because I would tend to agree with the redirection. The question boils down to, "How can I get the size of a pointer? `sizeof` doesn't do the trick." ... to which the redirection that it's impossible to get the size of a pointer, that this information has already been lost once the array has decayed into a pointer, is actually quite technically correct. Yet it's not helpful. In your case, what you really wanted to know was the size of a null-terminated string, for which the pointee contents actually provide enough information to deduce a size (`strlen`), but it would take the most careful inspection to understand that.

I don't know what to do about this dilemma -- high-volume question traffic vs. careful inspection of what was truly being asked. Filters can't work fast enough to shut down genuine duplicates, but at the same time, in the panic and desperation to do so, often innocent bystanders get hurt.

Comment: Possibly a suggestion for an additional function to the site for 'disagree'ing with single-user dupe redirection to bring in the more careful inspection that you deem to be necessary from other users to consolidate what the proper state of the question should be? In short, give the ability to ask for greater moderation of the application of dupehammer?

Comment: I don't know. It's awkward from the overseer view which is seeing a boatload of questions every day and trying to balance out the need to filter against the need to keep the site clean. To me these are mutually exclusive goals to filter and to help each individual -- both noble goals, but ones that fight each other. I think there needs to be some way, just at the broadest level, to kind of not make these two ideas fight each other so much.

Comment: @shiri Actually there is kind of a "disagree" option. Just edit your question. It'll bump it in the reopen queue where npeople can vote to reopen. I'd suggest making an edit specifying why the dupe target doesn't help you out. Don't make it ranty or meta, just state why the dupe is wrong in objective, rational terms. :)

Comment: If your problem is that the closed questions has useful answers which add something over those in the target, the right action is flagging for a mod to merge them, not revoking the dupe-closure. (disclaimer: I haven't read the specific question yet)

Comment: @Deduplicator Merging is very interesting -- I don't see it done too commonly. In the case of a merge, does the date of the Q&A update to the newest merge? Even though it shouldn't matter, I think it does -- to preserve the original momentum, I think a merge needs to bring the old Q&A back as though it was just posted the day the merge happened.... not just a simple bump, but show up in the new Q list to shine a spotlight on it.

Comment: The few times I decided to ask a mod for merging, it was always done. Now whether favoring the target more than due to the new answers bumping it makes sense, most often it doesn't, and I have no idea how to determine when it does algorithmically, nor am I aware of any way even for a mod to manually highlight it...

Comment: @Deduplicator I see. The awkward issue for me is that, even though it's probably not as it should be, the freshness of a Q can often have a lot to do with its views, its energy, its momentum. In those rare but not too rare cases where a Q is shut down really late, like after it already has 20 upvotes and bustling with activity, but marked as a dupe, it has a tendency to kill all that momentum and energy the Q had going for it. So I see it as kind of ideal if a merge could revive an old Q, give it that energy the new but duplicated Q had going for it. Sometimes the best answer....

Comment: @Deduplicator ... in those are pretty old, or simply not as good as the ones being provided for the duplicate.